# browser automatically generate a launcher icon on home screen for web apps android

Tags: javascript, android, browser, app-launcher

Is it possible to automatically generate a bookmark within the Android home screen using Javascript or a meta tag?

Answer (score 2):

This is really only possible if you write native code along with your mobile site. If you do, then you can write a webview inside of your native code that will allow your javascript to invoke your native code and add the shortcut by intent.